# How to configure useful feedback when newly set password does not comply with set policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, passwords, amazon-iam, password-policy

I've successfully applied a custom password policy for my IAM users in AWS:

`aws iam update-account-password-policy --minimum-password-length 64 --allow-users-to-change-password --password-reuse-prevention 24`

Next I force a password reset - this also works.
But the when I deliberately try to set the new password to a non-compliant one, I get this rather opaque error at the top of the page (https://us-east-1.signin.aws.amazon.com/changepassword):

> Either user is not authorized to perform iam:ChangePassword or entered password does not comply with account password policy set by administrator

Is there a way to configure useful feedback? Such as: `Password should be at least 64 characters`?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to customize this error message. There is an [AWS Developer Forums thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=268070) from 2017 that raises this issue, however the response appears to have only been to add "or entered password does not comply with account password policy set by administrator".

Unfortunately your only option is to communicate password complexity requirements through a parallel vector. Alternatively, if you [create accounts by setting a temporary password for the user instead of requiring a password reset](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html), you could (outside of AWS) template an email to send that to the user that includes instructions on password complexity.

[The API does actually clarify whether it was a password policy issue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ChangePassword.html), however.